# How to get Customer ID Through ActiveMerhant StripeGateway -(Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, activemerchant

I am using ActiveMerchant gem for the stripe payment in rails and I am getting confused how to create a new customer and get the customer id for future transactions. As per  Stipe [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards) first we need to create Customer and then save id for future payments.

```
# Create a Customer:
customer = Stripe::Customer.create({
    source: 'tok_mastercard',
    email: 'paying.user@example.com',
})

# Charge the Customer instead of the card:
charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
    amount: 1000,
    currency: 'usd',
    customer: customer.id,
})

# YOUR CODE: Save the customer ID and other info in a database for later.

# When it's time to charge the customer again, retrieve the customer ID.
charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
    amount: 1500, # $15.00 this time
    currency: 'usd',
    customer: customer_id, # Previously stored, then retrieved
})
```

But if I am looking into the [ActiveMerchant](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/Shopify/active_merchant/ActiveMerchant/Billing/StripeGateway#purchase-instance_method)  there is no method to create a customer, please anyone guide me.

Comment: For PCI compliance reason, I will recommend you to use Stripe's official Ruby library at https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby. 
It is much easier and more secure way to integrate with Stripe API

Comment: ActiveMerchant only allows you to do charges, you'd need to use Stripe's own gem (mentioned in @wsw's comment) to access the customer details.